# Unable to pass variable to database

Tags: php, plugin-development, wpdb

I'm trying to write a simple plugin which saves a backend form's inputs and selects to the db. Everything's fine until the script tries to pass the variables which store the field's values to the db. Here's my script:

```
ob_start();
$html = ob_get_clean();
if ( isset( $_POST["submit_form"] ) && $_POST["nume"] != "") {
$table = $wpdb->prefix."scoring";
$nume = strip_tags($_POST["nume"], "");
$prenume = strip_tags($_POST["prenume"], "");
$valoarecredit = strip_tags($_POST["valoare-credit-text"], "");
$venit = strip_tags($_POST["venit-text"], "");
$varsta = strip_tags($_POST["varsta-text"], "");
 $proprietate = strip_tags($_POST["proprietate-text"], "");
$istoricbc = strip_tags($_POST["istoric-bc-text"], "");
 $vechime = strip_tags($_POST["vechime-text"], "");
 $perioada = strip_tags($_POST["perioada-text"], "");
$data = array( 
        'nume_client' => $nume,
        'prenume_client' => $prenume,
        'valoare_credit' => $valoarecredit,
        'venit' => $venit,
        'varsta' => $varsta,
        'proprietate' => $poprietate,
        'istoric_bc' => $istoricbc,
        'vechime_loc_de_munca' => $vechime,
        'perioada_credit' => $perioada
    );

$wpdb->insert( $table, $data, '%s' );
echo "<p><strong>" . $table . $wpdb->dbname . Prenume: " . $prenume . "Nume: " . $nume . "Valoare credit: " . $valoarecredit . "Venit: " . $venit . "Varsta: " . $varsta . "Proprietate: " . $proprietate . "Istoric: " . $istoricbc . "Vechime: " . $vechime . "Perioada: " . $perioada . "</strong></p>";
}
// if the form is submitted but the name is empty
 else if ( isset( $_POST["submit_form"] ) && $_POST["nume"] == "" )
    $html .= "<p>You need to fill the required fields.</p>";
return $html;
```

As you can see, I tried debugging the script, thinking that there might be something wrong when I get the table name, db or one of the variables, but they have the right values.

I double checked and triple checked the field names, thinking I somehow mistyped one of them, but they are all fine.

Now, if I just replace those variables with '1' in the data array, the script works and everything is written to the db just fine (a whole new db record full of 1's).

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I just took a few hours away from the script and then I found the culprit... I did mistype the $proprietate variable when I assigned it to the db field (which is set to not NULL)...